# display spring security authentication object when SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, thymeleaf

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/main").permitAll();
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(successHandler());
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); // Session is STATELESS
}
```

I set spring security sessionpolicy to STATLESS

because I'm using JWT so that STATLESS would be better
but STATELESS cause one problem

it's impossible to dispaly authentication object in thymeleaf

```
<h1>[[${#authentication }]]</h1>
```

if I changed session policy I could display authentication object

but  but that's not what i want

in short

can i use authentication object with thymeleaf when spring's session policy is STATELESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form based log in requires a session, so marking as stateless would mean that the user is not available. Likely you can see the page because it is marked as permitAll which means no user is necessary to see it.

To fix this, you can switch to a form of authentication that is stateless too (i.e. it is included in every request). For example:

```
// @formatter:off
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .mvcMatchers("/index", "/main").permitAll()
        .and()
    .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); 
// @formatter:on
```

I'm also not sure about the syntax the themleaf template is using. For me, I use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1 th:text="${authentication?.name}"></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Then I use the following to expose the Authentication as a model attribute:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    Authentication authentication(Authentication authentication) {
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

I have a test that validates it works

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate rest;

    @Test
    void indexWhenAnonymous() throws Exception{
        ResponseEntity<String> result = rest.exchange(RequestEntity.get(URI.create("/")).build(), String.class);
        assertThat(result.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(result.getBody()).doesNotContain("user");
    }

    @Test
    void indexWhenAuthenticated() throws Exception{
        ResponseEntity<String> result = rest.exchange(RequestEntity.get(URI.create("/")).headers(h -> h.setBasicAuth("user", "password")).build(), String.class);
        assertThat(result.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(result.getBody()).contains("user");
    }
}
```

You can find the complete sample at https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-sample/tree/display-auth-stateless-thymeleaf which allows log in with the username `user` and password `password`.

Comment: thank you for ur answering. but how can I login
should I add login url and html?

Comment: If you want to use a stateless approach you need an authentication mechanism that supports providing the credentials every time. Form based authentication is intended to use state, so it will not really work with stateless authentication. In my example, the credentials are provided through basic authentication which will work for stateless authentication. You can see how to do that in the `indexWhenAuthenticated` test I provided.